# how to remove carriage return in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

All my data have carriage return in url field:
ex:
 [image]

see the cursor position.

After I remove manually the carriage return (with keyboard !), everything works fine:

[image]

(see the cursor position)

I tried:

```
UPDATE links set url= replace(url,'\r\n','');
UPDATE links set url= replace(url,'\n','');
UPDATE links set url= trim(url);
```

NOT good: How do I get rid of these carriage returns ?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `link` SET `url` = TRIM('\r\n' FROM `url`);
```

The function `TRIM()` will only remove spaces and not line breaks and other characters. As their documentation says, it has "Remove leading and trailing spaces" for `TRIM()`. But you can specify characters to remove.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Although the one you tried should work, also try:

```
update links SET url= TRIM(TRAILING '\r\n')
```

Another option:

```
UPDATE links SET url= REPLACE(url, '\r', '');
```

Btw, the above could also be formed like this:

```
UPDATE links SET url= REPLACE(REPLACE(url, '\r', ''), '\n', '');
```

This would remove both \r\n and \n

Comment: `log` should be `url`